# UK Date Format Issues

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime

I have a restaurant web based project that I am working on at the moment and am having problems with `Datetime`.

I have a `WebMethod` that adds a table booking to a SQL Server database.

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddTable(string first, string last, string email, long telephone, int people, string special, DateTime bookingDate)
{
    using (BookingLinqDataContext bl = new BookingLinqDataContext())
    {
        bl.AddTable(first, last, email, telephone, people, bookingDate, special);
    }
}
```

This is parsed data from an Ajax call:

```
$("#AddTableBut").click(function () {
    var firstName = $("#FirstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#LastName").val();
    var email = $("#Email").val();
    var telephone = $("#Telephone").val();
    var numberPeople = $("#NumberPeople").val();
    var date = $("#DateComing").val();
    var special = $("#SpecialReq").val();

    var Book = {
        'first': firstName,
        'last': lastName,
        'email': email,
        'telephone': telephone,
        'people': numberPeople,
        'special': special,
        'bookingDate': date
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/PeldonRoseService.asmx/AddTable",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(Book),
        success: function () {
            $("[id$=booking]").hide('blind', { direction: 'up' }, 2000);
            $("#BookNowBut").delay(2100);
            $("#BookNowBut").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

When I test this, I add a date to the corresponding textbox in the UK date format `dd-MM-yyyy`. However I am receiving this error from Chrome's Developer Toolbar:

> Message: 30-04-2014 is not a valid value for DateTime.

However if I use the American Date Format `MM-dd-yyyy` everything works perfectly fine.

Could the issue be my browser's culture information?

Comment: It cannot be the browser if you're not doing any sort of date formatting in the browser. You're simply sending a text box's contents to the server as a string, and it's the server that attempts to convert it to a `DateTime` value, at least basing on what I see in this question.

Comment: It may be easier to change your method signature to pass a string to the webmethod and in your c# code use DateTime.Parse() / DateTime.TryParse()

Comment: Used the .parse function like suggested and works perfectly! Thank you very much!!

Comment: That was just step 1.  Step 2 is to use query parameters.

Comment: @user3529183 if the `Parse()` function worked for you, why don't you add and that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the .parse function worked for me.

The jquery stays the same:

```
$("#AddTableBut").click(function () {
var firstName = $("#FirstName").val();
var lastName = $("#LastName").val();
var email = $("#Email").val();
var telephone = $("#Telephone").val();
var numberPeople = $("#NumberPeople").val();
var date = $("#DateComing").val();
var special = $("#SpecialReq").val();

var Book = {
    'first': firstName,
    'last': lastName,
    'email': email,
    'telephone': telephone,
    'people': numberPeople,
    'special': special,
    'bookingDate': date
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/PeldonRoseService.asmx/AddTable",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(Book),
    success: function () {
        $("[id$=booking]").hide('blind', { direction: 'up' },     2000);
        $("#BookNowBut").delay(2100);
        $("#BookNowBut").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
    }
});
```

});

However there is a slight change to the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddTable(string first, string last, string email, long telephone, int people, string special, string bookingDate)
{
Date time dt = DateTime.parse(bookingDate);
using (BookingLinqDataContext bl = new BookingLinqDataContext())
{
    bl.AddTable(first, last, email, telephone, people, dt, special);
}
```

}

Parse the date in as a string parameter and then use the .parse function like above to parse the string as a date. This date can then be parsed to the database using the linq query.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere, you have to parse the date string.  Consider one of the two following approaches:

**Server-Side Parsing**

- Pass the contents of the text box exactly as entered - which you are currently doing.
- Declare your `bookingDate` parameter as a `string` instead of a `DateTime`.
- In the method body, use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert the string to a `DateTime`.
- When doing so, make sure you are taking the user's culture into account.  A string like `"1/4/2014"` might represent January 4th, or April 1st.  The `Parse` and `ParseExact` methods will use the *current* culture by default.  If you don't have logic elsewhere in your app to set the thread's current culture to the culture of the user, then you can pass in a specific culture.  If you do *neither*, then you may not get the behavior you expect.

**Client-Side Parsing**

- In your JavaScript code, don't just pass what was entered in the textbox.  Instead, parse that string to a `Date` object or to a `moment` object ([using moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)).  The language and culture settings of the *browser* will affect how the value is parsed.
- Then format it in ISO-8601 format, such as `"2014-04-13"`  (year, month, day).
- Pass that string to your server.
- In your server code, you can leave the parameter as a `DateTime`, and not be concerned with culture settings.

Here's an example of client-side parsing with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that will fit into your code easily:

```js
var date = moment($("#DateComing").val(),"l").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Without moment.js, then you could do something like this:

```js
var dt = new Date($("#DateComing").val());

function zeroPad(n){ return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; }

var date = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + zeroPad(dt.getMonth()+1) +
                              '-' + zeroPad(dt.getDate());
```

(Since you are collecting a whole date and time, I would stay away from `toISOString` or `toJSON` methods and use one of the above instead.)